# Insert a Div Effectively when using JQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Jquery validation of form as follows:

```
$(this.initVariables.formId).validate({
     errorElement: "div",
     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element.parent());
     }
}
```

The problem is when an error appears, the form becomes distorted as follows:
[image]

What I want to do is to adjust effectively the neighbor field the same line as the error field as follows:
[image]

HTML code of div is:

```
<div class="relatedField>
    <div id="wwgrp_addForm_summaryData_firstName" class="wwgrp" style="float: left; padding-right: 6px;">
          <div id="wwlbl_addForm_summaryData_firstName" class="wwlbl"> 
              <label class="label" for="addForm_summaryData_lastName"> FIRST NAME </label>
          </div>
          <div id="wwctrl_addForm_summaryData_firstName" class="wwctrl">
               <input id="addForm_summaryData_firstName" class="storedPaymentInput_size4 alphabet" type="text" value="" name="summaryData.firstName">
          </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wwgrp_addForm_summaryData_lastName" class="wwgrp" style="float: left; padding-right: 6px;">
          <div id="wwlbl_addForm_summaryData_lastName" class="wwlbl"> 
              <label class="label" for="addForm_summaryData_lastName"> LAST NAME </label>
          </div>
          <div id="wwctrl_addForm_summaryData_lastName" class="wwctrl">
               <input id="addForm_summaryData_lastName" class="storedPaymentInput_size4 alphabet" type="text" value="" name="summaryData.lastName">
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i do this using jquery without changing the implementation of my form. I have lots of field beside this. Please help. Thank you.

My solution is

```
 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.insertBefore(element.parent());
     element.parent().parent().siblings().each( function () {
           var child = $(this).children("div.wwctrl");
        $("<div class='SPACE'>&nbsp;</div>").insertBefore(child);
      });
 }
```

But as you could see, it is not clean and after the correct validation, the div space is not removed.

[image]

Any idea on how to do this better.

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you just insert "ALPHABETS ONLY!" below instead of above to avoid the shift of both input elements?

Comment: Otherwise have a separate element that holds the error container while creating the markup itself

Comment: you can make more gap between `Label` and `Textbox` and for `error message` use  small `font`

Comment: Cannot do this.. requirement is very strict

Comment: Can you post the link to your page? @newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you look at the height of your "ALPHABETS ONLY!" element and just add that much padding/margin to the top of your other input field to push it down exactly that much?

This way, you would avoid creating any new elements, but you'd have to remember to remove this margin/padding when you get rid of the "ALPHABETS ONLY!" element.

Comment: the problem is the height is different for every browser

Comment: sure... but not by much. if you use `.outerHeight(true)` on your element, that'll be pretty damn close, and then just add a couple of pixels to account for potential browser differences?

Comment: well... it looks like you're the one that adds the error message in there, won't you be the one that takes it out?

Answer (score 2):

You could essentially create a blank div on top of the inputs and declare a width/height for them.. Like that your browser would calculate this 'blank space' from the get-go and you can insert the error message via $('divname').html. Just a thought. Kind of like this..

http://jsfiddle.net/ng8VQ/72/

Answer (score 1):

Since you've not posted the link to the page yet, there's no other choice but to assume and suggest bad answers which could do the job.

Do this:

```
$(this.initVariables.formId).validate({
     errorElement: "div",
     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         error.insertBefore(element.parent());
         error.insertBefore(element.parent().siblings());

         //Insert something here that will overlay all the other errors
         //a div maybe, with opacity=1 leading them to be not visible.

     }
}
```

Do remember to use the div with absolute positioning, or else it will put you in same situation.

Maybe this would give you an idea what I mean, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rH3Fv/)

Comment: **quote:** _"there's no other choice but to assume and suggest bad answers"_  ~  No, there's clearly another choice =>  Do not post an answer until more information is provided.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you check for clean validation, look at each other error box and check if the HTML error is empty. If it is empty, remove it. Although this is still a hacky-work-about.

```
element.parent().parent().siblings.each( CheckEmpty );

function CheckEmpty() {
    if ( $( this ).html()=="&nbsp;" ) {
        $( this ).remove();
    }
}
```

Or, if you give each empty error message a specific class, you could simply remove all those elements with that class name. However, this can be more troublesome as it will remove all of them. This will not work if they have errors on multiple field lines since by fixing one, it will remove all of them.

```
$( ".blank" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the whole thing in table. Inject `<tr>` and show the error inside the `<td>` of this new `<tr>`. I hope I was crystal clear.

Comment: Oh i forgot to say, use javascript or any other library to inject the tr

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id='register_frm' action='' method='post'>
<input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" value="">
 <div class='error-div'>  
<label class='error' for='firstName'></label>   
</div>
<input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" value="">
 <div class='error-div'>  
<label class='error' for='lastName'></label>    
</div>
<input type='submit' value='Register' />
</form>

$("#register_frm").validate({
    errorClass:'error',
    rules: {
    firstName: "required",
    lastName: "required"
    }
});

<style>
.error{
color:red;
font-size:12px;
}
.error-div{
height:15px;
}
</style>
```